# I have a problem with BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-web

When I connect the application to the phone, I run it, and this appears

It also appears in the DEBUG CONSOLE list, which is in blue and does not stop counting

`Exception has occurred. _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart': Failed assertion: line 188 pos 11: 'items.every((BottomNavigationBarItem item) => item.label != null)': Every item must have a non-null label)`

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried inserting the values ​​into the BottomNavigationBar

Comment: I have tried to fix the images you added to this post. I wonder if the first two are duplicates of each other. You probably don't need images anyway - images of code/error text are not helpful, since they are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers, and search engine robots. Always just use text.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a label to your BottomNavigationBarItem. It must not be null. Here's the example:

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    label: 'Some String'
);
```

Comment: thank you from the bottom of my heart ,
You're great , 
The program worked

Comment: @HydraBabakri Great, consider marking this reply as an answer ;)